# Why is my resource not available with namespace.Properties.Resources

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picturebox to which I am trying to add an image which is in my resources.

There was already an image under the resources folder and that one shows up in the context menu when I type:

*namespace*.Properties.Resources.

The extra image was added by me by right-clicking Resources and selecting "Add" then "Existing Item..."

I have changed the build action to "embedded resource"

But only the image already there shows up.

I can get to the image like this:

```
Assembly _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream _imageStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("myNamespace.resources.image.png");
Bitmap myImage = new Bitmap(_imageStream);
this.icon.Image = myImage;
```

but I don't understand why I can't get to it using:

```
this.icon.Image = myNamespace.Properties.Resources.image;
```

The fact that the other image can be got to without using the .png extension suggests that a name has to be supplied somewhere.  The properties of the other image don't give me any clues though (which has buildAction of None)

Can someone explain this to me please.

I'm using VS2012 Express

**EDIT:**

While the GetManifestResourceStream code above compiles okay, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Value of 'null' is not valid for 'stream'
```

So it seems that the resource is unavailable by both means.

Comment: There are *two* ways to embed resources.  First one is to add a file to your project and change its Build Action property to "Embedded Resource".  That's what you did or that code could not work.  The *second* way is the way you ought to use, given that the first snippet is rather brittle, use the Resource Designer.  Select Project > Properties > Resources.  Now you preferred syntax will also work.

Comment: You're a star - thank you